# How to set value to a map without copy constructor?

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy-constructor

Have to fill instances of a non-copyable class into a map. For example with this code:

```
#include <map>

class NoCopyClass
{
    public:
        NoCopyClass() {};
        NoCopyClass(int value)  {};

        NoCopyClass& operator=(const NoCopyClass&) = delete;

};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, NoCopyClass> my_map;
    my_map[3] = NoCopyClass(20);
}
```

This fails to compile unless you comment out the deletion of the copy constructor.
You can try it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/ByBh0NubU

What is the right way to add a new map element when the class is not copyable?

Huge thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add a defaulted rvalue (a.k.a. move) assignment operator, as in `NoCopyClass& operator=(NoCopyClass&&) = default;`?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [`emplace()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) to construct the object in place instead of copying an already constructed object:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, NoCopyClass> my_map;
    my_map.emplace(3, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cpp
#include <map>

class NoCopyClass {
public:
    NoCopyClass() {};
    NoCopyClass(int value)  {};

    NoCopyClass& operator=(const NoCopyClass&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, NoCopyClass> my_map;

    // 1. option

    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(3, 30));

    // or 2. option

    my_map.emplace(std::make_pair(4, 40));

    // or 3. option

    my_map.emplace(5, 50);

    // or 4. option

    my_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                   std::forward_as_tuple(6),
                   std::forward_as_tuple(60));

    // or 5. option (from C++17)

    my_map.try_emplace(7, 70);

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:33,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:33,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:33,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:33),source:'%23include+%3Cmap%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aclass+NoCopyClass+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++NoCopyClass()+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++NoCopyClass(int+value)++%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++NoCopyClass%26+operator%3D(const+NoCopyClass%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::map%3Cint,+NoCopyClass%3E+my_map%3B%0A++++my_map.insert(std::make_pair(3,+30))%3B%0A%0A++++//+or%0A%0A++++my_map.emplace(std::make_pair(4,+40))%3B%0A+%0A++++//+or%0A%0A++++my_map.emplace(5,+50)%3B%0A%0A++++//+or%0A%0A++++my_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,%0A+++++++++++++++++++std::forward_as_tuple(6),%0A+++++++++++++++++++std::forward_as_tuple(60))%3B%0A%0A++++//+or+(from+C%2B%2B17)%0A%0A++++my_map.try_emplace(7,+70)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+9.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Options:

1. uses `std::pair`'s move constructor,
2. uses `std::pair`'s converting move constructor
3. uses `std::pair`'s template constructor
4. uses `std::pair`'s piecewise constructor
5. if a key already exists in the container, it does nothing; otherwise, behaves like `emplace` except that the element is constructed as value_type